# Cycles render glitches

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts

Im having issues with rendering with cycles as the left side of the blade creates some sort of glitch. Any idea what might be causing this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.